# Node.js does asynchronous IO, how about Django?

Tags: django, node.js, asynchronous

http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

says, if you are blocked for DB (or any other IO call) from your Node.js, other users are not very much affected by it.

It also says, apache's thread-for-every-request model isn't as good as node.js for the above case.

I'm looking for how Django behaves when io is blocked and couldn't find a thing.
Oh my google..

Can anyone give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

No, due to WSGI being a synchronous interface. Try a look at http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ for python non-blocking IO

Comment: I'm talking about the job that django is trying to do requires 'io call' such as DB call, it could be another application server (for instance api-server) . I believe wsgi part is between client - django, not django - other server. Correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: You are correct sir! Take a look at this maybe, just came across it, haven't had time to read it yet. http://media.codysoyland.com/pdf/django-on-gevent.pdf

Comment: Django
•
Built around synchronous APIs
obj = Model.objects.get(pk=id)
cache_hit = cache.get(key)
response = view(request)
•
Gevent is a perfect fit
•
Green libraries and monkey-patching solve blocking

Comment: Kerry: thanks for the input. http://www.slideshare.net/mahendram/scaling-django-with-gevent This explains it slightly better but still missing pieces.

Comment: Glad I can help! I'm really interested in this now, be sure to share your findings!